# setInterval works when alert is included in if conditions, else it works only once

Tags: iframe, setinterval, javascript

this question might be seems to be the similar question asked previously but its not.

My question is following :
I have code snippet as follows :

```
    var i = 0;              

    function func2() {                  
    if (i==0){

    document.getElementById('frame1').contentWindow.opts[selected].setAttribute('name','channels');
    var strValue = document.getElementById('frame1').contentWindow.opts[selected].getAttribute('name');
   //alert("Attribute value set :" + strValue);
   document.getElementById('frame1').contentWindow.handleKeyCode(VK_ENTER);
   i++;

   }
   else if(i==1){

   // For Channels section -- "Get current channel details"
   document.getElementById('frame1').contentWindow.opts[selected].setAttribute('name','get');
   var strValue = document.getElementById('frame1').contentWindow.opts[selected].getAttribute('name');
   //alert("Attribute value set :" + strValue);
   document.getElementById('frame1').contentWindow.handleKeyCode(VK_ENTER);
   i++;

   }
   else if(i==2){

   // For Channels section -- "Set current channel details"
   document.getElementById('frame1').contentWindow.opts[selected].setAttribute('name','set');
   document.getElementById('frame1').contentWindow.menuSelect(1);
   var strValue = document.getElementById('frame1').contentWindow.opts[selected].getAttribute('name');
   //alert("Attribute value set :" + strValue);
   document.getElementById('frame1').contentWindow.handleKeyCode(VK_ENTER);     
   i++;

   }
   }

   $(function() {
      setInterval(function(){func2();}, 1000);
   });
```

In this the setInterval works only once i.e it executes only the first if condition. But as I enables the "alert" messages of all the conditions then the setInterval works fine.

I don't want the "Alert Messages" for this setInterval if conditions, it should executed each if elseif statment as per the condition and at given time interval.

I am enable to achieve this. Also i didn't find any satisfactory reference from the setInterval related questions in this forum. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: *Please*, don't bold huge chunks of your question. It's annoying.

Comment: why you tag this question with jQuery, this is pure Javascript, why dont you try with jQuery??

Comment: This is jquery only, above code snippet is inside $(document).ready(function(){ var $frame = $('#frame1'); $frame.ready(function () { ------------- }); only.

Comment: haha, well it is called through jquery, but there is no jquery in the actual function

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are getting an exception inside `func2` which make it seem like it is not running more than once. Reading .contenWindow when it is null. Try using try/catch to catch the exception. Or use a debugger.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your valuable reply actually the above snippet works fine when I add alert messages in each if conditions. as you can see i currently commented, if i uncomment those alert messages then its working fine. But i don't want alert messages to be displayed and still it should work same.